# Simplecursoradapter new constructor

Tags: android

The new constructor of the Simplecursoradapter class now requires another parameter that is flag what should be supplied in there.

new

```
SimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags)
```

depreciated

```
SimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to)
```

All the examples that i have seen till now use old constructor. I have no experience with flags till now i appreciate any help

Comment: Either  `FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY` or `FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing in `0` for the flags gives the default behavior, which does not observe for data changes or auto-requery for data (those cases should now use [Loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html)). The available flags can be reviewed [in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#CursorAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20android.database.Cursor,%20int%29)